# How to select multiple items in a listbox?

Tags: python, linux, tkinter, listbox

I have a listbox:

```
    self.listBox = Listbox(self.master,              
                           height = 34,
                           width = 38)

    self.listBox.grid(row = 3, column = 0, rowspan = 7, sticky = W)
```

There are many items in the listbox. I tried to select two of them by holding down the ctrl or shift key on the keyboard when selecting with the mouse, but it seems that by default it is not possible to select multiple items. How can I overcome the issue?

I'm using Python 3.5 on Linux Mint Xfce.

Comment: Normally you have to hold down the control or shift key when selecting multiple items by hand.

Comment: Of course I have tried that.

Comment: [documentation](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm). You have to set a selectmode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
self.listBox =Listbox(self.master, 
                       selectmode='multiple',              
                       height = 34,
                       width = 38)
```